# Angular ngrx: TypeError: Cannot freeze array buffer views with elements

Tags: javascript, angular, redux, ngrx

Im encountering an issue with ngrx. I have an array in my state to which i want to append objects. This actually works fine if i console.log them i can see that values in my store. But the redux dev tools and the console throw the error "TypeError: Cannot freeze array buffer views with elements".

I have a state that looks like this:

```
const state: State = {
  array: []
};
```

The Object i pass to my actions looks similar to this:

```
const obj = {attr: number, data: ImageData};
```

Where ImageData comes from a Canvas and is extracted with `canvas.getContext("2d").getImageData(...);`. It should be noted that this Object is huge with over 69000 keys with values from 0 to 255(RGBA).

And i append the new Object to the state/store like this:

```
createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(action, (state: State, action)=> {
    return {
      ...state,
      array: [...state.array, action.payload]
    }
  })
);
```

Furthermore i read that i should deepCopy Objects before passing them to the action so i did that with lodashs `copyDeep()`, but i got the same results.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The only reason you would need to deep clone an object is if the original will get mutated some how. Otherwise it is pointless overhead.

Answer (score 0):

You need state.array in your reducer.

```
return {
  ...state,
  array: [...state.array, action.payload]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort but i have this already in my Code i just had it wrong in the question. Im sorry

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I solved it by cloning the data that I pass to the dispatch method

ex:

```
const dataCloned = CloneDataInDeep.clone(dataToAdd);
this.store$.dispatch(actionToDispatch({ dataCloned}));
```

Another option that I have tried is to change this attribute value "strictActionImmutability" in the ngrx configuration from true to false

```
runtimeChecks: {
  strictActionImmutability: false,
  ....
}
```

Comment: What is CloneDataInDeep?

Answer (score 0):

I use Angular and came across that error.

For me, deep copying the array before the dispatch worked

```
const copyArray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array));
this.store.dispatch(actionDispatch.requestSth({ myArray: copyArray }));
```

Not the most beautiful solution, I know.

Edit:
Unfortunately the solution was not helpful because the objects inside the array lose the functions when strigified... So back to square one

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code. This will copy the entire object so the dependency will be removed.

```
const newlyCreatedArray = Object.assign({}, array);
```

For more details: [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign?retiredLocale=tr)